# Login and Logout views are they necessary? ( SimpleJwt+Django rest framework)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

So according to many examples out there.

some projects would actually build a Loggin view that uses the AccesToken and a Logout view that could use the Blacklist.

while others would just use AccesToken,Refresh , Blacklist directly and handle the login/logout from the frontend(a consumer like React,...) with out the need to use Views.py

i was wondering if one is better than the other, or is there any difference (performance wise, or security,...)

Thanks

Comment: Please can you be more clear? You will still need to create views.py to return JSON for React.

Comment: well that is actually my question,i just tried this repo https://github.com/veryacademy/YT-Django-DRF-Simple-Blog-Series-JWT-Part-3, there was no login view in django itself ,but in React end, it is working perfectly, and actually quite understandable, while i've been doing before was creating the views in Django end and generating access token etc..

Comment: The views have already been implemented as `TokenObtainPairView.as_view()` (for login) and `BlacklistTokenUpdateView.as_view()` (for logout) by in rest_framework_simplejwt package. So no need to create your own views but the do exist in the package.

Comment: You would need to implement your own views or serializers etc in case you do want to change some functionality and are not comfortable by defaults.

Comment: Here are the views https://github.com/jazzband/django-rest-framework-simplejwt/blob/master/rest_framework_simplejwt/views.py

Comment: alright, thank you very much for the explanations, that's really helpful